# How to populate a table with data intervals on postgresql with a function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the next tables:

[image]
[image]

I need to create/populate the third table as following:

[image]

I painted the cells to make easier to understand. If I need to spell what I need, would be as follows:

> Between 2018-06-05 and 2018-06-19 the value is 50.
>
> Between 2018-06-19 and 2018-06-21 the value is 150.
>
> Between 2018-06-21 and 2018-06-25 the value is 180.
>
> Between 2018-06-25 and 2018-07-05 the value is 200.

I need to create a function to do this but I can't do this, I spend all day thinking about this problem but unhappily I can't dev the script.

I tried use some `WHILE` but....not success.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the logic used to generate the two date columns in your expected output.  Can you explain what is happening there?

Comment: Is something like "timeline".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking you can `union all` the tables together and then use window functions to fill in the details:

```
select date as startdate,
       lead(date) over (order by date) as enddate,
       coalesce(newv,
                lead(prev) over (order by date)
               ) as value
from ((select date, null as prev, null as newv
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select dateupdate, prev, newv
       from table2
      )
     ) tt;
```

This adds an extra row for the last date.  If you don't want that, you can remove it by using an additional subquery and filtering it out.

Comment: Excelent my friend. Worked very well. Thanks for all! You're the MAN! Have a nice day.